# Como podria limitar una consulta en postgresql a un 50% de los datos cuando llame por la tabla

Tags: postgresql

Tengo que traer el 50% de los datos que contiene la tabla datos

es decir si tengo 10 lineas solo traer 5 pero sin usar limit 5, ya que tiene que ser constante dependiendo a la cantidad de lineas

```
Select * from datos
limit 50%
```

esto me genera error

como se podria hacer ?

Comment: Puedes almacenar en una variable conteo total de filas, dividir eso entre 2 y usar ese valor en el limit para solo traer la mitad del conteo total

Comment: @BetaM podrias ser un poco mas especifico, como un ejemplo

Answer (score 0):

Puedes intentar esto:

```
SELECT * FROM datos
LIMIT  ( Select count(*)/2 FROM datos )
```

La sintaxis de la clásula `LIMIT numero` dónde un número puede provenir de cualquier sentencia mira estos ejemplos:

Ejemplo 1:

```
SELECT * FROM datos
LIMIT  1
```

Ejemplo 2:

```
SELECT * FROM datos
LIMIT  1+2
```

Ejemplo 3:

```
SELECT * FROM datos
LIMIT  (select 5+5) -- Cuando se resuelve esta cláusula el valor escalar es 10 y se cumple lo establecido en la gramática.
```

Ejemplo 4:

```
SELECT * FROM datos
LIMIT  (SELECT * FROM TABLA [WHERE (CONDICION) ])
```

Conociendo que se desea conocer el 50%, este corresponde al conteo total entre dos, es decir :

```
SELECT count(*)/2 FROM TABLA
```

me cuenta el total de registro de la tabla TABLA y los divide en dos, dado que ese valor es un escalar es candidato a ser usado en la clásula LIMIT en Postgres.

Nota esta cláusula no es ANSI SQL y no sirve en todos los motores.

Comment: Podrias agregar una explicacion de lo que hace tu querry por favor? Le vendria bien tanto a OP como a cualquier persona que vea tu respuesta en el futuro.

Comment: Es correcto, había omitido la explicación.

Comment: Muchas gracias por la respuesta, @FabioAndrés, fue de mucha ayuda

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar la cláusula `TABLESAMPLE` si estas usando PostgreSQL 9.5 o superior,  con alguno de sus métodos (https://www.postgresql.org/docs/devel/sql-select.html#SQL-FROM)

tendrás un aproximado en el porcentaje del valor que le indiques, por ejemplo 50%

```
SELECT * FROM datos TABLESAMPLE SYSTEM(50);

SELECT * FROM datos TABLESAMPLE BERNOULLI(50);
```

Esto te selecciona datos aleatorios de la tabla, Cada método tiene sus caracteristicas

Comment: muchas gracias por la respuestas, aunque no me devuelve exactamente la mitad

Answer (score 0):

De forma general yo usaría esto:

```
select * from datos limit (select count(*)*0.5 from datos)
```

Donde ponemos en lugar de `0.5` el porcentaje que quisiéramos (dividido 100 obviamente), el `limit` redondea automáticamente si el resultado fuera `float` al menos en postgres 12, caso contrario hay que poner `::int`